# Logical Volume Partitions

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, lvm, kickstart

I am trying to incorporate Logical Volumes into the paritioning scheme for the VM I am creating, in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.1.  I am booting from an ISO Image and I have a Kickstart Script that runs the installation.  The script references a Hard Drive Configuration file that has the following outlined in it:

```
# Partitioning scheme for 60 GB HD

# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel
# Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr
# Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype="ext4" --size=256
part swap --fstype="swap" --size=16384
part /PV --fstype="ext4" – size=1 --grow --encrypted --passphrase=password
volgroup sysvg PV
logvol / --vgname=sysvg --size=5120 --name=root
logvol /tmp --vgname=sysvg --size=2048 --name=tmp
logvol /usr --vgname=sysvg --size=4096 --name=usr
logvol /home --vgname=sysvg --size=20480 --name=home
logvol /opt --vgname=sysvg --size=5120 --name=opt
logvol /var --vgname=sysvg --size=5120 --name=var
logvol /var/log --vgname=sysvg --size=10240 --name=log
logvol /var/log/audit --vgname=sysvg --size=5120 --name=audit
```

The kickstart.cfg file has the following information:

```
    #platform=x86, AMD64, or Intel EM64T
#version=DEVEL
# Firewall configuration
firewall --enabled
# Install OS instead of upgrade
install
# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $1$gkOgiLQh$ARiChNQJU0Goj6uQbkQhZ/
# System authorization information
auth  --useshadow  --passalgo=sha512
# Use text mode install
text
# System keyboard
keyboard us
# System language
lang en_US
# SELinux configuration
selinux --disabled
# Do not configure the X Window System
skipx
# Installation logging level
logging --level=info
# Reboot after installation
reboot --eject
# System timezone
timezone  America/New_York
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr
# Disk partitioning information
%include /tmp/part-include
# Repositories for package installation
repo --name=cdg-disk --baseurl=file:///mnt/source/Packages --cost=0
repo --name=cdg-repo --baseurl=file:///mnt/source/extras/cdg-repo --cost=0
repo --name=cdg-updates --baseurl=file:///mnt/source/extras/cdg-updates --cost=0
repo --name=cdg-epel --baseurl=file:///mnt/source/extras/cdg-epel --cost=0
# Package selection
# TODO: create our own cdg-core, cdg-management groups
%packages
@base
@core
@perl-runtime
@server-platform
@postgresql
@nfs
# TODO: remove this when our own RPMs depend on jre?
jre
%end

# Pre-installation Scripts
%pre

/mnt/stage2/extras/scripts/configurePartition.sh

%end

%post --nochroot

exec < /dev/tty6 > /dev/tty6 2> /dev/tty6
chvt 6

cp -r /mnt/source/extras /mnt/sysimage/tmp

chvt 1
exec < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2> /dev/tty1

%end
# Post-installation Scripts
%post 

exec < /dev/tty6 > /dev/tty6 2> /dev/tty6
chvt 6

/tmp/extras/scripts/main.sh

chvt 1
exec < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2> /dev/tty1
%end
```

When I start up the installation.  I get an error saying theres a problem with line 10 of the kickstart Mount Point Required.  (Line 10 is where rootpw)

I have been stuck on this and am a newbie can someone please help me?

Comment: I think part of the issue might be that the /PV partition I'm using on my physical volume might need to be created as a directory on my system so that it acts as a mountpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the top file is what is being used by Kickstart. If so, then I'd say line 10 is indeed in error. The format of the partition name in the part command is "pv.XXX" not "/PV".

Then, again, I still can't get this style of partitioning to work.